# Set display none for specific user

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to set css property as display none for a specific user. Its simple but however not working...

```
function wp_hide_link() {
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
if($user_id == 3){
echo "<style> .fieldset-shipping{display: none;}</style>";
}
}
add_action('admin_init', 'wp_hide_link');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `admin_init` action is the wrong hook to use. Change that to `admin_footer` (untested):

```php
add_action( 'admin_footer', static function () {
    if ( 3 !== get_current_user_id() ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<style>.fieldset-shipping { display: none; }</style>';
} );
```

You may need to adjust the CSS selector to override other styles.